# error installing fbprophet on google colab

Tags: facebook-prophet

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
> Running setup.py clean for fbprophet
> Failed to build fbprophet
> Installing collected packages: cmdstanpy, fbprophet
> Attempting uninstall: cmdstanpy
> Found existing installation: cmdstanpy 1.0.7
> Uninstalling cmdstanpy-1.0.7:
> Successfully uninstalled cmdstanpy-1.0.7
> Running setup.py install for fbprophet ... error

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1vvhi6y2/fbprophet_8696b1bf4d034ecdaf15a9df1efcaaf3/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1vvhi6y2/fbprophet_8696b1bf4d034ecdaf15a9df1efcaaf3/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-rf017it6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7/fbprophet Check the logs for full command output.

[fbprophet](https://pypi.org/project/fbprophet/)

Answer (score 0):

Just run this in a cell

```py
!pip install pystan==2.18.0.0
!pip install fbprophet
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `prophet` module instead of `fbprophet`. The `prophet` module is pre-installed on Colab. So it's not necessary to install it, just import it directly.

```py
import prophet
```